# Написание кросс-платформенных приложений на C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, monodevelop

Доброго времени суток! Есть потребность написать кросс-платформенное приложение на C#. Что можно использовать? С помощью гугла понял, что есть две возможности это реализовать - mono и .NET Core. Нужно написать простое консольное приложение. 
весь код писать буду на Windows в Visual Studio 2017, но приложение должно работать в Linux Ubuntu.  Какая из двух возможностей, упомянутых выше, подходит мне больше всего? Какие плюсы и минусы у mono по отношению к .NET Core и наоборот.

Comment: [.NET Core vs Mono](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37738106/net-core-vs-mono)

Comment: Это зависит еще и от того какое приложение вы  хотите. Net.Core сейчас поддерживает только Mvc  и консольные приложения, насколько я знаю. Mono может создавать какое-то подобие WinForms, WebFroms и WPF, а также кроссплатформенные мобильные приложения и mvc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET Core - если хотите поэкспериментировать. Вообще весьма стабильным и проверенным решением является Mono (ничего против .net core не имею). Скачиваете среду Mono Develop, создаете проект, выбираете консольное приложение и вперед. ".NET Core" в общем нацелен на более масштабные решения, которые нужно развертывать на разных платформах (например проекты на ASP.NET) или консольные приложения (опять же для нужд сервера), при его проектировании пытались уменьшить зависимости, повысить производительность, сделать сделать модульную архитектуру. GUI (WinForm,Etc) для Core нету, во всяком случае пока. Mono - это эквивалент .NET Framework для Linux/MacOs (тут вам и гуи и mvc, веб формы и т.д.

Comment: Вопрос по поводу mono. Разрабатывать можно только в Mono Develop? Просто мне более удобнее использовать visual studio.